# I am writing a nested function with ngFor. I want to bring parent categories with subcategories. But the function is looping

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I'm turning an object. I need to create a nested loop as well as the number of child elements. But the code is looping. I've never seen anything like it in Vue. Parent and Child elements had to return only once. Can you help me?

```
 categories: TableCategories[] = [
{
  categori_id: '1',
  categori_title: 'GİRİŞ',
  categori_counter: 10
}
```

]

```
<mat-tab-group align="center">
<mat-tab label="{{categori.categori_title}}" *ngFor="let categori of categories">
    <div *ngFor="let table of tables(categori.categori_id)">
        {{table}}
    </div>
</mat-tab>
```

```
 tables(categori_id) {
let arr = []
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  arr.push(index)
}
return arr;
```

}

[image: screen]

Comment: could you share the code

Comment: hi dude;
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rr9nhn 
but i cant see  any problem int stackbilitz same code on pc in looping

Comment: It seems to me that something is causing the change detection to fire which is re-rendering the list over and over. Are you sure this is the full code on your local?

Comment: Hi friend. i have lots of child component, module and service.  Unfurtunatly i cant share everythings and i cant find problem.